# Any sample real-time application using MFC threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I am trying to build a MFC windows application getting input from several devices and showing an analysis result on the monitor in real-time.  Of course, I have to use threads (both ui and worker) a lot. I started reading books like "Multithreading Applications in Win32" but still need help building the application.

If possible, I would like to learn from a good open source project in the same environment. Can you recommend one of them? Actually, any of them is fine as long as it's built with MFC using ui and worker threads, possibly working with devices.

I know following projects but would like to have another one if possible:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3wsyb55(v=vs.80).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/threads_and_mfc.aspx

UPDATE: I managed to find more samples. Following list of open source applications helped a lot.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/OpenSource_VC_MFC.aspx

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note, Windows is not a real-time OS so application will not be real-time, they might be close to it, but don't depend on it.
For a good start (thread, UI), have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/process_class.aspx

Comment: @Max According to this reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system , Windows CE is a real-time OS and MFC application can be still real-time. So I believe my question is still valid.

Comment: max.. nothing is a real time system.. A punch to the fact takes about 500ms to register as such to the victim. Paul.. add to that the ability to adjust the thread priority and a windows box becomes very close.

Comment: @baash05 Thanks! That's exactly what I was thinking. As Windows CE generally does not have performance power, why not using normal Windows with priority set.

Comment: This question is not a great fit for the StackOverflow site.  SO is for specific programming questions like, "I'm trying to compile this code but the compiler complains about construct XYZ."  Questions seeking general or conceptual advice would be better suited to a different site on stack exchange, perhaps programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @JohnDibling Moving to programmers site sounds great. Could you help me to do that? or Do I have to post this on the site again?

Comment: The community will decide what should be done with this question.  It so far has 2 votes to close, one of which is because it is "off-topic" with the suggestion that it be migrated to PSE.  If this question accumulates 5 votes to close and there are enough to migrate it to PSE, it will automatically be moved.

Comment: @JohnDibling I just voted to close this to migrate. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Just FYI, I'm not entirely sure that this would be best matched at PSE, either.  We send a lot of stuff over there that we apparently shouldn't.  That's one reason why we rely on the community to decide.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start here: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0798/c0798.aspx

Comment: I am not sure how any of those Q & A is related to my question.

Comment: Download the sample code. It demonstrates good usage of `AfxBeginThread`.

Comment: I think I mentioned about the sample code in my question. I rarely do this but gotta downvote this answer. You are presenting unrelated materials without any explanation while not reading the question at all.

Comment: You're free to vote as you wish. However, the provided sample does contain a simple UI with a worker thread - using a well designed wrapper class.